# Could a cracked password run as a command on the attacker's system?

Tags: password-cracking, data-leakage

I recently was made aware of 6 passwords that I use becoming compromised in data leaks, and they are now exposed in plain text.

I don't know how attackers go about cracking passwords or how they handle them when [credential stuffing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Credential_stuffing).

If, on websites that I'm not too concerned about being compromised on, I set my password as `rm -rf / --no-preserve-root`, could this possibly have consequences on the attacker machine, assuming they are using some form of automation to crack and plug passwords?

Comment: This is highly unlikely unless you are able to identify a vulnerability within a specific password cracking program. Unless the password was used directly on the command line and began with an `;` or other delimiter of commands.

Comment: @multithr3at3d sounds like a good answer - can you convert it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is like many other questions which can be simplified down to "could x be vulnerable to y", where the answer may boil down to "yes, it is possible, but unlikely". For example, I highly doubt that well-known and reputable password cracking software is going to straight up try to run the cracked passwords as commands (side note: it is unlikely that password in particular would be cracked unless it was in a dictionary).

However, it could be possible that a single attacker somewhere has glued together multiple scripts and made a mistake where a variant of your password would actually work. The password, as it stands, shouldn't pose a threat unless it is passed directly to a command line or call to `exec()`. Let's say the attacker has cracked your password and pastes it as an argument to a hypothetical program with one of these variants:

```
# ./hack_user_with_password_i_just_stole --user you@example.com --password rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
# ./hack_user_with_password_i_just_stole --user you@example.com --password "rm -rf / --no-preserve-root"
```

Both of these are harmless; although the first one won't likely work since the program will probably trip up on the spaces. But this could happen if it was pasted without paying attention.

To give the password some teeth, we can prepend it with `;`, `&&` or `||` so the shell treats it as a separate command:

```
# ./hack_user_with_password_i_just_stole --user you@example.com --password ;rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
# ./hack_user_with_password_i_just_stole --user you@example.com --password ";rm -rf / --no-preserve-root"
```

If you were unlucky enough to run the first command, the malicious command would indeed execute since the shell treats everything after `;` as a separate command from the first. The second command won't work, however, since the quotes cause the entire password to be passed as a single argument to the program.

Now, while pasting a password like this is unlikely, there are a couple other ways where it could happen. Maybe the attacker has a script that takes cracked passwords from a file and passes them to another program for purposes of credential stuffing, like you said:

cracked_passwords.txt:

```
user@example.com,password1234
<snip>
you@example.com,;rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
<snip>
```

hack_script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

with open('cracked_passwords.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        user, password = line.split(',')
        os.system("./hack_user_with_password_i_just_stole --user {} --password {}".format(user, password)
```

If the attacker is naive and doesn't plan for spaces in the password, the payload would work here. Even if they surrounded the arguments with quotes, it could be defeated by using additional quotes in the password. That said, each of these hurdles would require your password to be even more complex, reducing the likelihood that it would be cracked in the first place.

As you can see, while technically possible, this scenario is rather specific and unlikely to happen.